# Calculate a running total that works with relative date filters

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Union table of my various bank accounts to create a personal finance analysis dashboard.

I am trying to make a `Running Total` to show my total capital available at any given date. Using a `Running Total` `table calculation` works, just as much as using a `RUNNING_SUM()` `calculated field`. They both work up until I filter the dates. **So I am trying to find a way to make the running calculation work without being thrown off by Date Filters** (I would like to implement relative dates for visualisation in the dashboard).

My union table has the following relevant data columns:

- Order ID: Descending number from 1 for each entry per account.
- Date: Date of entry.
- Item: Entry name.
- Account: Name of bank account.
- Amount: `+ive` for credit or `-ive` for debit.
- Balance: balance after entry value for each given account.

So the table can look like this:
[image: Example source data table in tableau]

So on 07/05/2019 the Running total should be 229.64.

The running sum formula mentioned above is currently `RUNNING_SUM(SUM([Amount]))`, so if any dates are excluded via filter the running total doesn't add up to the right amount.

A way I can see around the problem could be to get the sum over all accounts of the last balance reading at a given date. The balance is a running total but only if the final entry per `time period` for all accounts are summed would it work. Would it be possible to make a calculated field that gets the last balance reading for each account at any given date and then sums them?

Or is there a simpler smarter way I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

This comes down to an [Order of Operations](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/order_of_operations.htm) problem.  Once you filter the dates the viz doesn't have access to the data anymore.

Your best approach would be to add the running sum to the data source before you bring it into Tableau.  Then the running sum isn't a calculated field dependent on the data in the Viz.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I figured as much, hence why I am saying it'd be nice if there was a way to utilise the balances from all accounts at the end of month, but if I understand correctly, Tableau doesn't have for loops? If so I just need to make a different table within my spreadsheet and link that too.